# JavaScript eval() and const

Tags: javascript, constants, eval, redeclaration

I just stumbled upon a strange JavaScript error using Mozilla Rhino as a JavaScript engine.

This one line script throws an error:

```
eval("const a = 5;");
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: redeclaration of var a.
```

I would expect this error, if the line is execute multiple times - but it is only executed once, as this one line is the whole program.

Can anyone explain, why this error occurs?

Comment: Odds are one of the other scripts you're including already declared a constant named `a`. Try removing scripts (particularly 3rd party if you know you didn't) from the head one by one until this error doesn't appear

Comment: How do you execute the JS with Rhino?

Comment: I executed it within Eclipse - there are no other scripts included. I suspect it is an error within Rhino, as it works with Chrome.

Comment: @ user1407611 try to verify its usage..
if (typeof(a) == "undefined")
{....}

Comment: Make sure that there are no other variable `a` in the same scope.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error in the Firefox console. `eval("const a = 5; a");` logs `5`.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce it with Chrome - I filed a bug against Rhino

Answer (score -3):

There is no const type in javascript. You will have to use this instead

eval("var a = 5;");

Comment: Actually, there is, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: Yes, but its not totally standard, as you can read in your page "The current implementation of const is a Mozilla-specific extension". Yes, it works in chrome but...

Comment: That's right - however, it works if I move it out of the eval(), I just fails within eval()

Comment: Then try using the var type instead of the const. Maybe const is not implemented to the core.

Comment: @zon7 He did that in Rhino, which is Mozilla's JS engine. He's not looking for crossbrowser solution, but for the explanation of the error.

Comment: Seems so, I think I will file a bug against Rhino, it works in Chrome and so it should in Rhino.